# What is the best way to diagnose and profile MySQL in live production server?

Tags: mysql, statistics, profiling, monitoring

What tools/methods do you recommend to diagnose and profile MySQL in live production server?

My goal to test alternative ways of scaling up the system and see their influence on read/write timing, memory, CPU load, disk access etc. and to find bottlenecks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all you should set up some kind of monitoring with e.g.:

- [MySQL Enterprise Monitor](http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/monitor.html)
- [MONyog](http://www.webyog.com)
- [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) (free)
- [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) (free)
- [MySQL Activity Report](http://gert.sos.be/en/) (free)

Other may helpful tools: [mytop](http://jeremy.zawodny.com/mysql/mytop/) [innotop](http://innotop.sourceforge.net/) [mtop](http://mtop.sourceforge.net/) [maatkit](http://www.maatkit.org/)

In addtion you should enable logging [slow-queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/Slow_query_log.html) in your my.cnf.

Befor you start to tune/change parameters you should create some kind of
test plan and compare the before/after results to see wether your changes
made sense or not.

Answer (score 3):

This is something that I have worked on quite a bit.

- [MonYog](http://www.webyog.com/en/) - MySQL monitoring service.  We use this in production.  It is not free but has a lot of features, including alerts and historical data.
- [MySQL Enterprise Monitor](http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/monitor.html) - available with MySQL enterprise (i.e., not cheap)
- Roll Your Own!

About the roll your own option:

We actually developed a really cool monitoring application that uses [RRD tool](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/) (used by the common MRTG) and a combination of MySQL statistics, and system stats, such as iostat.  This was not only a great exercise but gave us a ton of flexibility to monitor exactly what we want from a single interface.

Here is a [Brief Description](http://www.mysql.com/news-and-events/newsletter/2004-01/a0000000301.html) of some approaches to building your own stats.

One of our big motivations for rolling our own, even though we also use MonYog, was to track disk statistics.  Disk i/o can be a major bottleneck, and the standard MySQL monitoring systems do not have i/o monitoring.  We use [iostat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iostat) which is part of the [systat](http://pagesperso-orange.fr/sebastien.godard/) package.

We have an interface that displays graphs of MySQL statistics next to disk i/o stats, allowing us to really get an overall picture of how the MySQL load is affecting disk i/o.

Before this, we really had no idea why our production applications were getting bogged down.  We discovered that disk i/o was a major issue, and that MySQL was creating a lot of temporary tables on disk when we were running complex queries.  We were able to optimize our queries and improve disk performance dramatically.

Answer (score 2):

[Jet Profiler](http://www.jetprofiler.com/) for sure

Answer (score 0):

[Vote http://tinyurl.com/vote-gif](http://tinyurl.com/vote-gif) add to list:

- Maatkit
- dbForge studio for mysql
- [Jet Profiler](http://www.jetprofiler.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Also add to list: RHQ 4 (open source) -- http://rhq-project.org/